# Can I share a protected workbook on a network while still using macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to share a workbook on a local network, the workbook is protected and only edited through macros and userforms. It works beautifully when it is not shared, each macro unprotects the workbook makes the edit and then re protects the workbook. however when the workbook is shared, it gives this error and does not let the code run.

Method 'Unprotect' of object '_Worksheet' failed

is there any way to keep this a protected workbook that is only edited by macros? and another tough question is some sheets allow selecting cells but no edits while other sheet's cells are unselectable, and I need that to stay true. Any help would be great, Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can use any feature ***that is available*** in a shared workbook while workbook sharing is enabled, and can use any feature that is available in a protected workbook while workbook protection is enabled.

Note that you cannot view the workbook's code while it is shared, but you can still run macros.

Share Workbook and Protect Workbook are separate features that both restrict what actions can be taken in the current workbook, and your code will need to turn each of them off before taking actions those features would prevent.

All of the below are properties or methods of the workbook object.

**Workbook protection:**

`Protect(Optional password)` is a method that turns workbook protection on, as Ribbon command Review | Protect Workbook.

`Unprotect(Optional password)` is a method that turns workbook protection off, as Ribbon command Review | Unprotect Workbook. The `password` argument is required if workbook protection was enabled using a password.

**Share Workbook feature:**

`MultiUserEditing` is a read-only Boolean property that indicates whether the Share Workbook feature is currently on.

`ExclusiveAccess()` is a method that takes no arguments and disables the Share Workbook feature. A side-effect of this is preventing other active users in a shared workbook from saving their changes to the original file.

The Share Workbook feature does not have its own method, instead use the workbook's `SaveAs` method with the argument `AccessMode:=xlShared` to turn it on (which requires saving the workbook anyway).

And in case that wasn't complex enough, there's *another* protection feature that applies to the Share Workbook feature.

**Protect Shared Workbook feature:**

`ProtectSharing(optional SharingPassword)` is a method that enables Sharing Protection, as the Ribbon command Review | Protect Shared Workbook.  When this feature is on, the Share Workbook feature cannot be turned off (i.e. you must turn off this protection first).  Using this method will also turn on the Share Workbook feature, if it is not already on.

`Unprotect Sharing(optional SharingPassword)` is a method that turns off Sharing Protection (allowing the Share Workbook feature to be subsequently disabled). The `SharingPassword` argument is required if a Protect Shared Workbook was enabled using a password.

**Reading:**

I tried to keep this as simple as I could (believe it or not). I strongly recommend reading about the members of the [workbook object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-object-excel) and the [share workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) feature, and do lots of testing, as there are many nuances to learn.